# Checking whether a file is being written to with std::fstream

Tags: c++, io

I am writing to, and reading from, a file called "results.dat", using `std::fstream`. This is done asynchronously, with the "read" and "write" function running in entirely different C++ programs. I want to check that the file is not currently being read before I write to it.

Suppose that my data is an array of 10 floats, then my "write" function looks like:

```
std::ofstream file_out("results.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
file_out.write((char*)&data, 10 * sizeof(float));
file_out.close();
```

And my "read" function looks like:

```
std::ifstream file_in("results.dat", std::ios::binary);
file_in.read((char*)&data, 10 * sizeof(float));
file_in.close();
```

If the file "results.dat" is currently being read, I then want to make my "write" function wait, in a loop, until it is no longer being read. How can I implement this?

Comment: Is everything in the same process (multiple threads etc.), or different processes?

Comment: The read and write are in 2 different programs

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LockFile()` function on Windows or `flock()` for Linux/Unix.

Comment: `flock()` is only advisory, and won't work over NFS in any case.

Answer (score 1):

**For synchronous cases** `std::ios::tie`.

The `tie()` is used to ensure that output from a tied stream appears before an input from the stream to
which it is tied. For example, `cout` is tied to `cin`:

```
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
int num;
cin >> num;
```

This code does not explicitly call `cout.flush()`, so had `cout` not been tied to `cin`, the user would see the request for input.

Here is another example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::ostream, std::cout, std::cin
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

int main () {
std::ostream *prevstr;
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open ("test.txt");

std::cout << "tie example:\n";

*std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into cout";
prevstr = std::cin.tie (&ofs);
*std::cin.tie() << "This is inserted into the file";
std::cin.tie (prevstr);

ofs.close();

return 0;
}
```

Further reading [here](http://perl.plover.com/yak/flock/).

**For asynchronous cases using** `flock()`:

Example:

The lock file creation must be atomic. The pre-standard  `<fstream.h>` library used to have an `ios::noshare` flag that guaranteed atomic file creation. Sadly, it was removed from the  library, which superseded `<fstream.h>`. As a result, we are forced to use the traditional Unix file I/O interface declared in `<fcntl.h>` (under Unix and Linux) or `<io.h>` (Windows) to ensure an atomic operation.

Before a process can write to the data file, it should obtain a lock like this:

```
#include <fcntl.h> // for open()
#include <cerrno> // for errno 
#include <cstdio> // for perror()
int fd;
fd=open("password.lck", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL)
```

If the `open()` call succeeds, it returns a descriptor, which is a small positive integer that identifies the file. Otherwise, it returns `-1` and assigns a matching error code to the global variable `errno`. The `O_CREAT` flag indicates that if the file doesn't exist, `open()` should create it. The `O_EXCL` flag ensures that the call is `atomic`; if the file already exists, `open()` will fail and set `errno` to `EEXIST`. This way you guarantee that only a single process at a time can hold the lock.

You check the return code of `open()` as follows:

```
int getlock() // returns the lock's descriptor on success
{
      if (fd<0 && errno==EEXIST){
      // the file already exist; another process is 
      // holding the lock
      cout<<"the file is currently locked; try again later";
      return -1;
      }
      else if (fd < 0){
      // perror() appends a verbal description of the current
      // errno value after the user-supplied string
      perror("locking failed for the following reason");
      return -1;
      }
      // if we got here, we own the lock
      return fd;
}
```

Once a process owns the lock, it can write to the data file safely. When it has finished updating the file, it should delete the lock as follows:

`remove("password.lck");`
At this moment, the data file is considered unlocked and another process may access it.

**or using:** `pthread_rwlockattr`

```
#define _MULTI_THREADED
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "check.h"

pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;

void *rdlockThread(void *arg)
{
int rc;

printf("Entered thread, getting read lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_rdlock()\n", rc);
printf("got the rwlock read lock\n");

sleep(5);

printf("unlock the read lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_unlock()\n", rc);
printf("Secondary thread unlocked\n");
return NULL;
}

void *wrlockThread(void *arg)
{
int rc;

printf("Entered thread, getting write lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_wrlock()\n", rc);

printf("Got the rwlock write lock, now unlock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_unlock()\n", rc);
printf("Secondary thread unlocked\n");
return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int rc=0;
pthread_t thread, thread1;

printf("Enter Testcase - %s\n", argv[0]);

printf("Main, initialize the read write lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, NULL);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_init()\n", rc);

printf("Main, grab a read lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_rdlock()\n",rc);

printf("Main, grab the same read lock again\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_rdlock() second\n", rc);

printf("Main, create the read lock thread\n");
rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, rdlockThread, NULL);
checkResults("pthread_create\n", rc);

printf("Main - unlock the first read lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_unlock()\n", rc);

printf("Main, create the write lock thread\n");
rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, wrlockThread, NULL);
checkResults("pthread_create\n", rc);

sleep(5);
printf("Main - unlock the second read lock\n");
rc = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_unlock()\n", rc);

printf("Main, wait for the threads\n");
rc = pthread_join(thread, NULL);
checkResults("pthread_join\n", rc);

rc = pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
checkResults("pthread_join\n", rc);

rc = pthread_rwlock_destroy(&rwlock);
checkResults("pthread_rwlock_destroy()\n", rc);

printf("Main completed\n");
return 0;
}
```

Here are few useful resources: [1](http://perl.plover.com/yak/flock/), [2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) and [3](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared).

Comment: Does this work even if the read and write are coming from two different programs?

Comment: Downvote from me, because I fail to see how streams from different processes can be tied, and even if, it´s only a small part of the problem.

Comment: @deviantfan `p=ios.tie(os)` Tie output stream `os` to `ios` ;
`p` is a pointer to the previously tied stream or `nullptr`.

Comment: ...so? What part of that code line did come from another process?

Comment: @deviantfan you are right, I was thinking in terms of pointers to streams, but the solution lies in elsewhere (threads and locks).

Comment: @deviantfan I've just finished  updating it. Hope it is better now. P.S. Thanks for the remarks!

Comment: This is interesting. I was always taught that files are locked automatically on a per-program basis with the caveat "Always remember to close your filestreams because if you don't they may remain open after your program ends." I would then naively assume the OP problem would be a non-issue as the file would error out as "already in use".

Comment: @Casey Closing files is always good, independent of the locking stuff. And if and how it´s locked for which access by default depends on the OS, and often can be controlled with OS-specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Unix? Use a [process-shared](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared) [pthread_rwlock](http://www.die.net/search/?q=pthread_rwlock&sa=Search&ie=ISO-8859-1&cx=partner-pub-5823754184406795%3A54htp1rtx5u&cof=FORID%3A9).

Answer (score 0):

If both processes are running on the same machine, then you can use an interprocess mutex. Only one process at a time is allowed to interact with the data file (the resource).

Interprocess communication is different on all OSs, but the boost library provides a uniform interface for all common systems.

The code would look something like this:

writer:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "data_file_access_mutex");

void write_function() {
    scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::ofstream file_out("results.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    file_out.write((char*)&data, 10 * sizeof(float));
    file_out.close();
}
```

reader:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
named_mutex mutex(open_or_create, "data_file_access_mutex");

void read_function() {
    scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(mutex);

    std::ifstream file_in("results.dat", std::ios::binary);
    file_in.read((char*)&data, 10 * sizeof(float));
    file_in.close();
}
```